# Sceintific notation to number in xls file - python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

im downloading an xls file from the web using selenium.
now,i want to use the data in it with pandas, but 1 column includes numbers in scientific notation.
is there a way to change them to numbers?
im trying to use the data in the excel, and transfer some of it into google sheet for my team to use, but if i cant figure out how to send the numbers and not the scientific notations, it wont work.

thanks,

Avi

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this:

1. your data is imported as string, so we need to split it at `e` to get our power of 10 out:

   `df = pd.DataFrame({'sci_num' :['6.2345e20'] })`

   `df[['num','exp10']] = df['sci_num'].str.split('e', expand=True)`
2. Then you need to use these two columns to get your results:

   `df['sci_num_corrected'] = df['num'].astype(float) * (10 ** df['exp10'].astype(int))`